# Compare installed deb package with deb file

Tags: deb

I have some problems with one deb package installed on my ubuntu server. I want to make sure that the files that are installed in my system from that package are the same as they are in a deb file.

What is the easiest to to check if the installed deb package has no changes from the original files and if there are some change to see the diff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debsums:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/debsums.1.html

> NAME
>   `debsums` - check the MD5 sums of installed Debian packages
>
> DESCRIPTION
>   Verify  installed  Debian package files against MD5
>   checksum lists from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums`.
>
> **debsums** can generate checksum lists from deb archives 
>   for packages that don't include one.

Comment: For some reason, does not work for files in `etc`: `dpkg -S /etc/pulse/system.pa` is `pulseaudio` but in `debsyms` the file is absent.